# Does Google Cloud SQL support JSON datatype?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

JSON datatype is supported in mysql from 5.7.8 onwards.

[Google cloud sql faq](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#version) - says second generation instances are on 5.6 and 5.7. Minor version updates are deployed as they are released, with no further action required on your part.

Can anybody tell me what exact version does google cloud sql is using right now or whether it supports JSON datatype.

Comment: JSON support in mysql link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current version is 5.7.11 and you are able to use JSON types.

You can check the version yourself using `SELECT @@version;`:

```
MySQL [(none)]> select @@version;
+-------------------+
| @@version         |
+-------------------+
| 5.7.11-google-log |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.12 sec)
```

Comment: Could I have found this in documentation somewhere ?

Comment: From the version command our instance is on "5.6.31-log". So not everyone just gets JSON support unfortunately.

Comment: If you have a 5.6 instance then obviously you can't use 5.7 features.

Comment: FYI, current version is now 5.7.14 on Cloud SQL

Answer (score 3):

JSON field types were [added in MySQL version 5.7.8](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

The current version in Google Cloud SQL is MySQL v5.7.11.

**So yes**, JSON colum types are supported.